# ST_DWithin is returning all the data in the table

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, nearest-neighbor, st-dwithin

I am new to PostGIS and currently struggling with `ST_DWithin` function.

I have a table `stores`, which stores lat and long of locations in Denmark in the `location` column as `geometry` and with SRID 4326.

Here's the screenshot of the table:

[image]

I am trying to find the nearest stores withing the 5 km radius from a specific lat and long.
Here's my query

```sql
SELECT  id, location 
FROM    stores 
WHERE   ST_DWithin(
            location, 
            ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.5053379,55.7655287), 4326), 
            5000);
```

But the problem is that this query returns all of the records in the table.

I thought this might be due to the fact that unit of SRID 4326 is degrees and I am trying to find in meters. So I tried to reproject it with [SRID 5643](https://epsg.io/5643) which projects on the map of Europe and because my data is from Denmark.

The query for this is:

```sql
SELECT  * 
FROM    stores
WHERE   ST_DWithin(
            ST_Transform(location, 5643), 
            ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.5053379,55.7655287), 5643),
            5000);
```

But this query is returning empty records, i.e. no record is returned.

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to use meters, cast your geometry to geography in the ST_DWithin function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   stores 
WHERE  ST_DWithin(location::geography, (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.5053379,55.7655287), 4326))::geography, 5000);
```

A side note:  You can't use ST_SetSRID to transform coordinates.  The point coordinates you have are in SRID 4326.  What you could do, if it were necessary is this:

```
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.5053379,55.7655287), 4326),5643)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solved my problem.
The other method that worked for me was transforming the operands into 5643 SRID.
I was wondering what's the difference between converting it into geography like your suggested, and using ST_Transform to convert the SRID's.
Does ::geography also converts the SRID of the coordinates?

And again thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: The geography type uses an ellipsoid to calculate distances in meters.  It's not transforming the coordinates.  It's useful for calculating distances in geographic coordinate systems like 4326.  5643 is a projected coordinate system or planar coordinate system.  It's representing that section of the earth as a flat plane, while 4326 is representing it as an ellipsoid.  In 5643, distances between points are a straight line.  In 4326, the line is curved.

Comment: One other thing is that it's less expensive for the database to use the geography type than to transform all the coordinates to another coordinate system.

Comment: It's also possible to generate a covering index on `Geography(location)`, so the ST_DWithin can leverage a spatial index.